# Bundle Install not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Over the last few days my bundle install has not been working. Every time I give a bundle command (bundle update, bundle install and bundle) I get this error:

```
sh: /c/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/bin/bundle: "c:/Program: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Which ruby:    `/c/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby`

Which bundle:`/c/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/bin/bundle`

In case anyone is confused I am on windows. And the bundle should be in the railsinstaller folder the which bundle folder doesnt even exist. Not sure why this error started suddenly, but it only occurred in the last few days. Bundle was running fine before that. Not sure what might have caused it.

Comment: are you using rvm gemset..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of `bundle` command may be `#! /c/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/bin/ruby`.  In this case, `/c/Program` is treated as an interpreter.  There is no way to escape spaces.
Try re-installing ruby to other directory that does not contain any spaces. (e.g. `C:\ruby`)

Comment: Just to be clear, ruby is installed under /c/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby, not sure why rails is suggesting bundle is located in program files (I had ruby installed in there long ago, but no longer using that dir).